# How to draw a state diagram, and which drawing software or online drawing website can I use?

Tags: android, uml, draw, diagramming

How can I  draw  a picture  like this :

http://developer.android.com/images/activity_lifecycle.png

Does the marker of this picture use some kind of software from an online drawing picture website?

Because of the appearance, I don't think this picture is created by yEd, visio and XMind.

Comment: This question looks to be off-topic. StackOverflow is meant for programming problems, not recommendations for diagramming software. At a glance I'd say that picture was made in Visio (Which is expensive), but there are tons of free diagramming tools out there.

Comment: As you can see from [Wikipedia: List of Unified Modeling Language tools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unified_Modeling_Language_tools) some tools create just drawings, only pictures, while some tools create real UML models in the [XMI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Metadata_Interchange) format which can be used to generate code, refactor the model or generate cross-reference documentation etc. The tools you have mentioned fall into the "just pictures" category

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hey here is very nice tool which you can use online as well as chrome extension.

http://www.gliffy.com/

You can draw different types of diagrams as you want.
I personally used as chrome extension. This tool is totally free.

Sample drawing

[image]

You can have more customize colors for object, object border, lines, text etc. 
Good luck.

Comment: i think the http://developer.android.com/images/activity_lifecycle.png  UI is different from the picture what is created at http://www.gliffy.com/ .
Anyway   ,thanks .

Comment: yes you can create exactly same just explore the gliffy properly will can find exactly same look.

Comment: Can you show me a  demo picture which picture has the  same look with what i give and it is created by presenation .
just a samll demo picture is enough

Comment: I added sample image that i just created for you.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.visual-paradigm.com/solution/freeumldesigntool/

Try this tool its free and works great ....